# Terraform 14 template_file and null_resource issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to use **null resource** using **local-exec-provisioner** for enabling the s3 bucket logging on load balancer using the template file. Both of the terraform file and template file *(lb-to-s3-log.tpl)* are on same directory **"/modules/lb-to-s3-log"** however getting an error. Terraform file looks this way:

```
data "template_file" "lb-to-s3-log" {
  template = file(".//modules/lb-to-s3-log/lb-to-s3-log.tpl")
  vars = {
    X_INFO1    = var.INFO1
    X_INFO2    = var.INFO2
    X_INFO3    = var.INFO3
  }
}
resource "null_resource" "lb-to-s3-log" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws elb modify-load-balancer-attributes --load-balancer-name ${var.LOAD_BALANCER_NAME[0]} --load-balancer-attributes ${data.template_file.lb-to-s3-log.rendered}"
  }
}
```

**WHERE:**

```
var.INFO1 = test1
var.INFO2 = test2
var.INFO3 = test3
```

**AND TEMPLATE (TPL) FILE CONTAINS:**

```
{
  "AccessLog": {
    "Enabled": true,
    "S3BucketName": "${X_INFO1}-${X_INFO2}-${X_INFO3}-logs",
    "EmitInterval": 5,
    "S3BucketPrefix": "${X_INFO1}-${X_INFO2}-${X_INFO3}-logs"
  }
}
```

**ERROR IM GETTING:**

```
Error: Error running command 'aws elb modify-load-balancer-attributes --load-balancer-name awseb-e-5-AWSEBLoa-ABCDE0FGHI0V --load-balancer-attributes {
  "AccessLog": {
    "Enabled": true,
    "S3BucketName": "test1-test2-test3-logs",
    "EmitInterval": 5,
    "S3BucketPrefix": "test1-test2-test3-logs"
  }
}
': exit status 2. Output: 
Error parsing parameter '--load-balancer-attributes': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {
/bin/sh: line 1: AccessLog:: command not found
/bin/sh: line 2: Enabled:: command not found
/bin/sh: line 3: S3BucketName:: command not found
/bin/sh: line 4: EmitInterval:: command not found
/bin/sh: line 5: S3BucketPrefix:: command not found
/bin/sh: -c: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/bin/sh: -c: line 6: `  }'
```

**ISSUE / PROBLEM:**
The template file successfully updates the variable assignments (X_INFO1, X_INFO2, X_INFO23).  Seems like the issue is on the **${data.template_file.lb-to-s3-log.rendered}** of the aws cli command.

Same error when I tried to substitute the file from **lb-s3log.tpl** to **lb-s3log.json**.

I'm using Terraform v0.14, I followed the process of enabling s3 bucket for log storage of amazon classic load balancer from this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-access-logs.html#enable-access-logs-console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is happening because you need to format the [JSON to be escaped on the command line](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-shorthand.html) or to [write the JSON as a file and then use `file://` to refer to it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html).

Wrapping your JSON in single quotes should be enough to escape the shell issues:

```
data "template_file" "lb-to-s3-log" {
  template = file(".//modules/lb-to-s3-log/lb-to-s3-log.tpl")
  vars = {
    X_INFO1 = var.INFO1
    X_INFO2 = var.INFO2
    X_INFO3 = var.INFO3
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "lb-to-s3-log" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws elb modify-load-balancer-attributes --load-balancer-name ${var.LOAD_BALANCER_NAME[0]} --load-balancer-attributes '${data.template_file.lb-to-s3-log.rendered}'"
  }
}
```

You can use the `local_file` resource to render a file if you'd prefer that option:

```
data "template_file" "lb-to-s3-log" {
  template = file(".//modules/lb-to-s3-log/lb-to-s3-log.tpl")
  vars = {
    X_INFO1 = var.INFO1
    X_INFO2 = var.INFO2
    X_INFO3 = var.INFO3
  }
}

resource "local_file" "elb_attributes" {
  content  = data.template_file.lb-to-s3-log.rendered
  filename = "${path.module}/elb-attributes.json"
}

resource "null_resource" "lb-to-s3-log" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws elb modify-load-balancer-attributes --load-balancer-name ${var.LOAD_BALANCER_NAME[0]} --load-balancer-attributes file://${local_file.elb_attributes.filename}"
  }
}
```

A better alternative here though, unless there's something fundamental preventing it, would be to have Terraform managing the ELB access logs by using [the `access_logs` parameter to the resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elb#access_logs):

```
resource "aws_elb" "bar" {
  name               = "foobar-terraform-elb"
  availability_zones = ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b", "us-west-2c"]

  access_logs {
    bucket        = "foo"
    bucket_prefix = "bar"
    interval      = 60
  }
}
```

You might also want to consider moving to [Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) or possibly [Network Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html) depending on your usage as ELBs are a deprecated service.

Finally, it's also worth noting that the [`template_file` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file) is deprecated since 0.12 and the [`templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) is preferred instead.

Comment: thank you @ydaetskcoR, your 1st recommendation which is adding single quotes fixed it.